# Install Perl module with dependencies

Tags: linux, perl, raspberry-pi, cpan, raspbmc

I'm trying to install a Perl module like this:

```
pi@raspbmc:~$ sudo cpan HTTP::Date
```

CPAN gets the file, the checksum is OK, and it uncompressed successfully.

But I got this error:

```
Using Tar:/bin/tar xf "HTTP-Date-6.02.tar":
Couldn't untar HTTP-Date-6.02.tar: 'Cannot allocate memory'
```

**How can I fix this problem?**

My file system:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mmcblk0p2   15G  2.1G   12G  16% /
/dev/mmcblk0p1   69M  8.1M   61M  12% /boot
```

I tried:

```
curl -L http://cpanmin.us | perl - App::cpanminus
```

But when I do

```
sudo cpanm HTTP::Date
```

I got this error:

```
-bash: cpanm: command not found
```

Comment: what about `free -m`? Typpically, when your error talks about memory which cannot be allcoated, check that you have allocatable memory ;)

Comment: [Installing perl dependency automatically in perl](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14066907/installing-perl-dependency-automatically-in-perl/14067234#14067234)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can confirm that the final answer to my question is:

```
sudo curl -L http://cpanmin.us | perl - --sudo App::cpanminus
```

Answer (score 2):

This is unfortunately the tell-tale sign of a [memory leakage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_leak). This command

```
ps --sort -rss -eo rss,pid,command | head
```

will tell you who the culprit is. Solving a problem like this is way above my pay grade, since it can basically be done only by the program/system developers. You may try to contact them to report the problem.

Edit:

Don't you have the curl command wrong? Should it not be

```
sudo curl -L http://cpanmin.us | perl - --sudo App::cpanminus
```

instead?

Comment: This is why I'm trying with cpanm but not found. Any idea ?

Comment: Not much of a choice, I am afraid.

Comment: Could you pls check the Edit to my answer?

Comment: Thanks my cpanm cmd was wrong. Why readd --sudo ?